# How can i more effectively programming for this situation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, helper

I'm a newbie in Jquery and i want to change this code more short and
effetive.

This is my code in the below and this code check the checkbox and change the
value. anyway anybody know about this jquery, please help me.

```
function fn_checkboxChange(){
    $("#redng_author_y").change(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
            $("#redng_author").val($(this).val());
        }
    })
    $("#redng_author_n").change(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
            $("#redng_author").val($(this).val());
        }
    })
    $("#redng_author_y").change(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
            $("#regist_author").val($(this).val());
        }
    })
    $("#updt_author_y").change(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
            $("#updt_author").val($(this).val());
        }
    })
    $("#updt_author_n").change(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
            $("#updt_author").val($(this).val());
        }
    })
    $("#delete_author_y").change(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
            $("#delete_author").val($(this).val());
        }
    })
    $("#delete_author_n").change(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
            $("#delete_author").val($(this).val());
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function setChangeListener(elem, targetElem){
    $(elem).change(function(){
              if($(this).is(":checked")){
              $(targetElem)).val($(this).val());
             }
           });
     }
}
```

then call that function for all such sets:

```
function fn_checkboxChange(){
    setChangeListener( "#redng_author_y", "#redng_author");
    setChangeListener( "#redng_author_n", "#redng_author");
    setChangeListener( "#updt_author_y", "#updt_author");
    setChangeListener( "#updt_author_n", "#updt_author");
    setChangeListener( "#delete_author_y", "#delete_author");
    setChangeListener( "#delete_author_n", "#delete_author");
}
```

Or if frequently many checkboxes map to the same input, you could:

```
    function setChangeListener( targetElem, ...elems){
      elems.forEach(function(elem){

        $(elem).change(function(){
              if($(this).is(":checked")){
                $(targetElem)).val($(this).val());
             }
           });
     }); 
   }
```

and

```
function fn_checkboxChange(){
    setChangeListener(  "#redng_author", "#redng_author_y", "#redng_author_n");
    setChangeListener(  "#updt_author", "#updt_author_y","#updt_author_n");
    setChangeListener(  "#delete_author","#delete_author_y","#delete_author_n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a class and a property to your checkboxes

#### HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" class="mycheckbox" data-target="someinput1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="mycheckbox" data-target="someinput2" />
<input type="checkbox" class="mycheckbox" data-target="someinput3" />
<input id="someinput1" ... />
<input id="someinput2" ... />
<input id="someinput3" ... />
```

#### JS

```
$(".mycheckbox").change(function(){
      if($(this).is(":checked")){
          $("#" + $(this).data("target")).val($(this).val());
      } 
 });
```